# What is the Fourier transform (in the distributional sense) of $x \log(|x|)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to find the F.T. of $x \log(|x|)$. Any hints?

Comment: What is the definition of the Fourier transform?  (That's my hint.)

Comment: I think I can get it, via derivatives of distributions, by looking at the integral of $\sin(kx)\log(|x|)/(x)$ from 0 to infinity. However, I am not sure how to evaluate this integral.

Comment: @Titus Quite a lousy hint that is.